# How to get data from custom list view adapter and pass to intent put extra?

Tags: android

I have `setOnItemClickListener` codes:

```
userListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String user_name = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
        Log.i("data_items",user_name);
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,user_name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

The log gives me:

```
pacakge.name.TableName@3131
```

Every row clicked gives me a different number at the end. For example

```
pacakge.name.TableName@4131
```

Is it the database of my SQLite? How to read in onClickItemListene of my custom list adapter?

Can anyone help me?

---

The codes for `ArrayAdapater`

```
private class UserListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserList> {

        private ArrayList<UserList> items;
        public UserListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int textViewResourceId, @NonNull ArrayList<UserList> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            this.items = objects;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if(v == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.user_list_item,null);
            }

            UserList userList = items.get(position);
            if(userList != null)
            {
                TextView usernameTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.usernameTextView);
                TextView fullnameTextViewFeatured = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fullnameTextViewFeatured);
                if(usernameTextView != null)
                {
                    usernameTextView.setText(userList.getUser_name());
                }
                if(fullnameTextViewFeatured != null)
                {
                    fullnameTextViewFeatured.setText(userList.getFull_name());
                }
            }

            return v;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put the code of adapter please

Comment: ArrayAdapter @Blackbelt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can do like this,

```
userListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        UserList userList = (UserList)parent.getItem(position);

        String user_name = userList.getUser_name();
        Log.i("data_items",user_name);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,user_name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Every rows clicked gives me different number at the end. For example

that's the implementation of `Object.toString`. Your adapter holds a dataset of type `TableName`, not of String. The line

```
String user_name = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
```

is wrong. It should be

```
 TableName tableName = (TableName) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

after casting to the right type, you can access `TableName`'s fields.

**Edit**.

After seeing your adapter, it looks like you are using `UserList` as data object, so the right cast should be `UserList` and not `TableName`, which is not what the Logcat is showing tho

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Muthu give me the answer that I could understand..

Comment: How to pass all data to putExtra? For example
`i.putExtra("userData",parent.getItemAtPosition(position));` Is it correct?

Comment: Only if the object is parcelable. [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) an example

Comment: How about my case?Sorry I'm quite new in android.

Comment: Google for it. It has bin answered tons of times